# How to execute a function when a Reacter Router is triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-router

I'm using the package Reacter Router to create and manage the routes of my application.

I am using an OAuth authentication system, which returns the following URL to my application:
http://localhost/login-meli?code=1234567890

I need that each time this route with the query "code" is triggered to execute a certain function, which as an example, can be: `console.log('It works!')`

I tried the code below and it worked, but I didn't find in the documentation how can I specify a specific query. I also noticed that when I add other lines of code an error is returned.

```
<Route exact path="/login-meli" render={() => (
    console.log('works!!!')
)}/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I specify a specific query"?  Also, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters) hook from `react-router-dom`.

```js
import { Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

Then in your route:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const code = params.get('code');
  if (code === '123456789') {
    return (<div>It Works!!!</div>);
  } else {
    return (<div>404 (you can redirect to an error page</div>);
  }
}
```

Then, for your Router:

```
<Route exact path="/login-meli"><MyComponent /></Route>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm getting this error: ./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'useLocation' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: I'm using Reacter Router Dom version 5.0.0

Comment: Hello. I changed the way I was doing the import to the following way and the error disappeared. But now I am getting another error. Here is how I am importing and the error obtained:
import {useLocation} from 'react-router'

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://fb. me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Make sure you are following these rules: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: I updated the code to something which should work a little better

Comment: Hello!

Thanks for your help.

I tried again but another error was returned: https://prnt.sc/rlvw6k

I will give you the relevant files that can help you determine the cause. I am importing the "useLocation" module from the "react-router". Which is very strange because as you gave me the official documentation I shouldn't be able to call it that. Follow the files. App.js: https://pastebin.com/wznPu1qg /// package.json: https://pastebin.com/v44XVJBB

Comment: useLocation should be imported from react-router-dom and not react-router

Comment: You might need to upgrade to react-router-dom 5.1 or greater